# How can I turn a polygon into a separate object?

Tags: 3ds-max

[image: Fighter jet i'm building. my first 3ds max creation]

I'm trying to turn those wings/canards/engines into different objects, so they won't be affected by the smoothing I'll do later on. 
PS: don't mind that little glitch on the wing, that only happened due to the view "pos".
PS 2: Any comments on my fighter jet? (any obs or suggestions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit Poly Modifier > Edit Geometry > Detach**

[image]

This is not reccomended, you better clasify the polygons in different smoothing groups as explained in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Iswm1xKtGs) tutorial.

The fighter jet looks great, but it looks better firing missiles **;)**

Comment: Thank you so much haha, i'm gonna see the tuts right now!